# Creating a wrapper function to accept variable argument for inner function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am creating a wrapper function to pass argument to some inner function call. The inner function has option to receive optional params.

**Actual Function**

```
 filterByColumn(
    fieldName: string,
    predicate?: string,
    matchCase?: boolean,
    actualOperator?: string
  ) {
    
  }
```

**Wrapper**

```
 wrapperFunc(...args){
    this.somethingElse.filterByColumn(...args); // <---- not working 
 }
```

Why is not accepting using spread operator in this way ?

Comment: Isn't this Typescript? And what does "not working" mean: is there a compilation error? A runtime error? Or no errors, but also not the desired result?

Comment: Please show how you are calling  `wrapperFunc(...args)`

Comment: This is not valid JavaScript. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and describe the errors you get.

Comment: You could use something like `wrapper(...args: Parameters<typeof filterByColumn>)`

Comment: @Mitya this is typescript

Comment: Sure, but it was tagged as JS only until someone edited it.